# Writing new Quartz.net jobs to Xml

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am planning to use RAMJobStore for Quartz.net. From my reading, we can configure jobs in an Xml and have the Xml plugin read the jobs at runtime and fire them

But is there an API to write new jobs or update existing programatically to the Xml

Comment: Ravi, if you think my answer is good enough, don't forget to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can find anything like that but you can write your own.
This is a silly sample.
Have a look at it. It might help:

```
jobschedulingdataSchedule[] jbSchedule = { new jobschedulingdataSchedule() };

jobdetailType[] jobs = {new jobdetailType() { description = "Blah" } };
triggerType[] triggers = {new triggerType() { Item = new simpleTriggerType() { description = "Blah" } } };
jbSchedule[0].job = jobs;
jbSchedule[0].trigger = triggers;

var quartzConfig = new QuartzXmlConfiguration20();
quartzConfig.version = "2.0";
quartzConfig.schedule = jbSchedule;

var quartzJobsXml = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "quartz_jobs.xml");
using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(quartzJobsXml))
{
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Quartz.Xml.JobSchedulingData20.QuartzXmlConfiguration20));
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, quartzConfig);
}
```